# diff characterwise

Tags: diff, file-comparison, vimdiff

Is there a stable tool (option/plugin of an existing tool: vimdiff, diff, etc) in Linux to do diff between two text files characterwise?

I would like to see the longest common subsequence between my two files highlighted. There is a classic polynomial-time [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) for that, but the standard tools seem to only work line by line.

Answer (score 2):

Good old `cmp` does a characterwise diff. It's been a part of UNIX for about 40 years.
https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cmp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition&arch=default&format=html

Unfortunately, it stops at the first differing character, so I don't know if this answer is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I just ran a `cmp -bl ...` after finding this answer and it reported multiple differences and their positions.  My version is `cmp (GNU diffutils) 3.6`.

Answer (score 2):

Install [`diffchar`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4932) ([Github link](https://github.com/vim-scripts/diffchar.vim) for those using a plugin autoloader). Since v4.7, with the plugin enabled, Vim automatically shows more exact differences:

[image]

- You can press <kbd>F7</kbd> (the default keymap) to toggle between the usual and the plugin. Reassign with:

  ```
  nmap <silent> <key> <Plug>ToggleDiffCharAllLines
  ```

  replacing `<key>` with an appropriate key code.
- You can use more colors:

  ```
  let g:DiffColors=100
  ```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work across lines, best I can tell. However, common regions are left *un*-highlighted (and folded, if they grow too long), so you might be able to take advantage of that.

---

Copied from [my Vi and Vim Stack Exchange post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/500/205).